# Pycharm Community Edition: "Unable to display frame variables"

Tags: pycharm

I get this error in the debug pane (replacing the variables) whenever Pycharm is stopped at a breakpoint on one project, which uses Flask. I created a new project to test this. The variables displayed in a breakpoint in this project; however they were not displayed on the exception breakpoint that resulted from having a nonexistent file in the run configuration.

Anyone have any ideas of what's going on?

Comment: I had this issue when running a script I wrote in python2.7, PyCharm was configured to use python3.4 by default... not sure if this is the same issue you were having but I hope it helps

Comment: I had a similar problem with remote debug. I solved it review all of my interpreter and run/configuration configurations. When I opened my Remote Interpreter configuration PyCharm started to update some files in the remote host and everything returned to work properly.

Comment: Hi, I also have this issue. I use PyCharm 2016.2 and use remote debugger. All I got is `Unable to display frame variables`. When I try to evaluate an expression, all I got is `Attribute not found: qualifier`. I haven't got the solution yet.

Local debugger is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for my problem here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20198

Basically, you just need to update your pydev using the one that attached in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using the remote debugger. I solved it by reinstalling the `pydev-debug.egg` distributed along with PyCharm. (This was another advice in the link from @ismailsunni's answer.)

(In my case, on OS X, here's the shell command I used after activating my virtualenv:

```
$ easy_install /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/debug-eggs/pycharm-debug.egg
```

The location on Windows or Linux will be different, obviously.)

Comment: As someone not very familiar with the JetBrains environments, how does one reinstall a .egg file?

Comment: I believe `easy_install` will overwrite the existing installation. Works for me, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I just updated to v2016.2 and get the same, BUT ONLY for the remote debugger. The local debugger works just fine. The remote debugger shows "Unable to display frame variables".

Comment: You should post this kind of "answer" as a comment to the question, because it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @mstuebner see my answer for your problem. It works in mine.