# Pycharm debug breakpoints not working

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I just imported a python project using pycharm and tried to add breakpoints to debug an issue. But the pycharm seems to be stuck on the statement "unable to display frame variables" and when I run step over, the pycharm seems to hang indefinitely. Can anyone tell me what the issue maybe?

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38948657/1198772

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pycharm Community Edition: "Unable to display frame variables"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34300737/pycharm-community-edition-unable-to-display-frame-variables)