# Why does PyCharm say "Unable to display frame variables" in debug mode?

Tags: debugging, pycharm

I have several python projects loaded in one pycharm workspace. All but one I can step into normally. One project, however, when I set a breakpoint on, say, the first line of the boilerplate, pycharm says it's `Collecting data...` for about 10 to 20 seconds then says `Unable to display frame variables`.
Trying to step over or into the code freezes pycharm for another 20 seconds.

PyCharm still stops at breakpoints, I can see the stack and, with some patience, click on the frames.

[image]

- I've checked the project configuration and everything seems the same as the other projects, or consistent from one project to another, including the Project, Environment variables, Python interpreter, Interpreter options (none), Script and Working directory.
- I've tried running the project in a separate workspace with the same results.
- I've reinstalled the debugger as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34300737/pycharm-community-edition-unable-to-display-frame-variables)
- I've upgraded to 2016.3

I was using PyCharm 2016.2.3 with `Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 4.1.1 (x86_64)`, now PyCharm 2016.3

What am I missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should put the Pycharm Debugger in `gevent compatible` mode.

> File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Python Debugger > Gevent compatible

The lines you removed probably had a purpose and you shouldn't delete them without knowing the consequences.

Comment: Of course, but the one who put them there told me it was ok to remove them.

Comment: Thanks, it solved my issue. Any idea what is this option and why does it solve it ?

Answer (score 3):

The code, which I didn't write myself, contained the following:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
```

Removing those lines resolved the issue.