# pycharm debug pygraphivz program shutdown with collecting data and timeout

Tags: python, pycharm, pygraphviz

you can repeat this error by debug bellow code:

from pygraphviz import * 
A = AGraph() 
a=1 # add breakpoint here

when debug stop on the line 'a=1', the Variables window shows 'collecting data ...', and then changes  'unable to display frame variables'

PS: my os system is Win10, python version is 2.7.8-64, PyCharm version is 2016.3 and 2017.1 EAP.

Answer (score 0):

this is answered here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45617125/4217317

You should enable "Gevent compatible" debuging:

> File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Python Debugger > Gevent compatible

Comment: You are RIGHT，Thank you！